# Rendering a view based on XML data

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP MVC Application I am populating the content present in a view based on data from XML files.

What my question is, am I doing this the best way? Surely there has got to be a more efficient and easier way to do what I'm doing here.

Here is an example of the markup in my XML file:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Content>
  <!-- P1: Customer details -->


  <ContentItem>
    <key>Header_CancelImg</key>
    <value>~/Content/mainpage/images/close.gif</value>
  </ContentItem>

  <ContentItem>
    <key>Header_CancelText</key>
    <value>Cancel this application</value>
  </ContentItem>
```

So, I am deserialzing the contents of this XML file like so:

```
 using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path)))  {
     XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Content));
     pageContent = serializer.Deserialize(ms) as Content;
 }
```

All good. Now, based on this, what is the best way I can populate my view based on this content? Let me show you what I mean, and how I'm doing it now (very horribly):

```
@model <project.Models.Content> // This content object contains Content object where the deserializer is present as shown above

@foreach (var contentItem in Model.Item2.contentItemList)
{
    @if(contentItem.key == "Header_CancelImg")
    {
        <img src="@Url.Content(contentItem.value)">
        continue;
    }
    @if(contentItem.key == "Header_CancelText")
    {
        <p>@contentItem.value</p>
        continue;
     }
} // and so on
```

Is there a more easier way I can do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you gave your `Content` class a default property, you could access the data from your model by referencing the key names without having to iterate over all the different possible keys.  I have shown a private dictionary property which is lazily initialized on the first hit.

```
public class Content
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> contentItems;

    public string this[string key]
    {
        if (contentItems == null)
        {
            contentItems = contentItemList.ToDictionary(i => i.Key, i => i.Value);
        }
        if (contentItems.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return contentItems[key];
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }

    //other properties
}
```

Then your razor code could be like this:

```
@model project.Models.Content

<img src="@Url.Content(Model["Header_CancelImg"])">
<p>@Model["Header_CancelText"]</p>
```